# Non-shared operation and NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, oop, notsupportedexception

I'm developing a library to map ports in Nat devices. These Nat devices use different protocols (and their versions) to map ports, get the external ip address, find available ports, list them, release them, etc.

So, I have one class for each of them:

- UpnpWanIPConnection1
- UpnpWanIPConnection2
- UpnpWanPPPConnection1
- UpnpWanPPPConnection2
- Pmp
- Pcp

Each of those share a few common operations like AddPorMapping, GetExternalIP, RemovePortMapping then, they implement an interface INat.

The library can be used as follow:

```
var natDevice = NatDiscovery.Discover();  // it returns an INat instance
natDevice.AddPortMapping(100, 100, "tcp");
```

The problem is some of them includes extra operations, eg. GetAllMappings while the rest don't. Then, if I include those non-shared operations as part of the interface, those devices that don't implement the operation (because is not part of the protocol that they support) will require to throw a NotSupportedException and that is very bad for who uses the library. Take a look:

```
var natDevice = NatDiscovery.Discover(); 
try{
   list = natDevice.GetPortList();
}
catch(NotSupportedException)
{
   // sorry, your device donnot support listing
}
```

I was thinking about properties like CanGetPortList, CanDoThis, CanDoThat but I don't like it.

Is the current approach (throwing NotSpportedException) the best way to do this?

Comment: Look at how some .NET classes handle similar issues. Dictionary<K,T> for example has a [TryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx) method to address a similar situation as you face here. Why not do something like "TryGetPortList", "TryDoThis", etc. in the same manner? Chances are that .NET programmers are already accustomed to this "TrySomething" convention. Or, you use the [Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) type for methods that return or not return a primitive value.

Comment: This is a great question but I think you'd find a better answer over at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are precedents in the Framework for "capability" properties to indicate to callers that members will throw a `NotSupportedException`.

Examples:

- `IList<T>.IsReadOnly` => if false, `IList<T>.Add()` and similar will throw
- `DbProviderFactory.CanCreateDataSourceEnumerator`

Personally in your situation I would add the `Can...` properties, but it's a subjective decision and you seem to be aware of the trade-offs you need to consider.

Comment: Sure, I know about the "capability" properties however, are they correct or just the result of a poor design? I mean, wouldn't be better to have a IReadOnlyList? That is my question about, is my design correct? If yes/no, why?

Comment: @Iontivero - all design is trade-off, so I don't think you can talk about "correct" or "incorrect".  And IReadOnlyList<T> is implemented by IList<T> so doesn't say anything about capabilities, only that the consumer doesn't want to be able to modify the list.  Multiplying the number of interfaces to expose different capabilities also adds complexity.

Comment: Agree. I was thinking about these approaches and yes, it's all about trade-off so, I will let it as it is (NotSupportedException) and will analyze the capability properties issue, they can be usefull in some scenarios. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating different Interfaces for those special cases, and try casting your type:

```
public Interface IPortListGetter
{
   void GetPortList();
}

var natDevice = NatDiscovery.Discover(); 
var portGetter = natDevice as IPortListGetter;
if (portGetter != null)
{  
    portGetter.GetPortList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit from your interface to other interfaces, so you would have a core interface and inherit fancy interfaces from that, so you can choose your optimal interface for any class.

Comment: If some of the devices are able to doFoo, then you can inherit an interface from the main called Fooable and implement Fooable for the devices which are able to doFoo.

Comment: Well, not really, he did not mention that you can inherit interfaces so you do not have to declare repeatedly methods in your interfaces in the case when more interfaces should be capable to do the same thing. If in all cases you support a doFoo method, then you can declare it in your core interface and inherit it into the other interfaces, so you will not have to declare doFoo in all your interfaces, as inheritance will help you.